# WKInterfaceTable get scroll position (contentOffset.y)

Tags: watchkit, wkinterfacetable

In `UITableView` I can call `tableView.contentOffset.y;` in order to get where the user has scrolled. However, WatchKit's `WKInterfaceTable` doesn't support that. Is there any way to get the scrolling position in the `WKInterfaceTable`?

Use case why this is necessary:

- user is in the middle of a table
- table updates
- table scroll jumps to top
- user has to scroll down again

I am able to scroll down programmatically with `self.messageTableOutlet.scrollToRow(at: (size-1)` but the user doesn't always want to get thrown to the end of the table. He also doesn't want to get to the top, he just wants to stay there.